# how to get value from seekbar android

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm trying to get value from seekbar, that i've set before as bellow :

```
SeekTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() <= 3){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(0);
                    period =7;
                } else
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() >= 3 && SeekTime.getProgress() <= 8){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(5);
                    period =30;
                }else 
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() >=8 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=13){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(10);
                    period = 90;
                }else 
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() >=13 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=18){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(15);
                    period = 180;
                }else 
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() >=18 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=23){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(20);
                    period = 270;
                }else 
                if (SeekTime.getProgress() >=23){
                    SeekTime.setProgress(25);
                    period = 360;
                    }

                System.out.println(period);

                new LoadData(baseURL+period).execute();
            }
```

but there's no data that loaded, because my `baseURL` not get value from seekbar, is there anyone can tell me where's my fault?

Comment: are u getting period value in  System.out.println(period); line?

Comment: no... i just want to check in that line, am i get period value, i try to get period value in new LoadData(baseURL+period).execute();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821614/getting-percentage-value-from-seek-bar

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/11/how-to-get-the-current-progress-on-your-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: @RachelGallen sorry, this is not what i need